# Cookbook get and set dynamic URL

Tags: chef, artifactory, curl

There is a static Artifactory URL being used to grab a semantically versioned artifact and deploy it to JBoss.  The deployment aspect of the cookbook is already fleshed out.  However, I would like to make the URL "dynamic".  In other words, get the most recently published artifact from Artifactory.

**Example URL**
https://myartifactory.com/releases/com/package/helloworld/1.0.0/helloworld-1.0.0.war

A Jenkins pipeline exists for this artifact that deploys to Artifactory.  So, if 1.1.0 were to be released, it's URL would look like the following:

**1.1.0 URL**
https://myartifactory.com/releases/com/package/helloworld/1.1.0/helloworld-1.1.0.war

You can see that the directory in Artifactory changes, as well as the name of the artifact.  How can I set up the cookbook to always grab the latest version from Artifactory?

Comment: From artifactory [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact), replace your static version number by `[RELEASE]` to get the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

You should use of the [Retrieve Latest Artifact](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact) endpoint. It uses the [repository layouts](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) to know what is the version in your artifact path, so you want to make sure those are set right for you. In this case, it's a standard Maven layout, which is the default for Maven repo, so you're all good.